# How to turn Bluetooth ON in Lenovo E46

Tags: bluetooth

I have a problem where I can't turn on the bluetooth on my Lenovo E46 laptop.

Laptop Details
 - Lenovo E46
 - Windows 7 32-bit

Problems 
- The bluetooth light is not lit (WiFi is lit). 
- The bluetooth icon is not in the system tray. 
- There are no settings in 'Control Panel' for bluetooth. 
- There are no drivers in 'Device Manager' for bluetooth.

On the Youtube, I learnt to check for 'fsquirt' and i was happy to find it in the system32 folder in my laptop... but it is not able to find any bluetooth device when run...

I tried to run SetupBtwDownloadSE.exe but is gets stuck and asks for bluetooth device to connect and does not proceed...

I have only 1 switch for turning the WiFi ON but no switch for Bluetooth..

Answer (score 1):

Generally Lenovo laptops have single switch for WiFi  and Bluetooth.

I think you don't have bluetooth driver installed for your notebook. You can download it from [here](http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/lenovo-e-series-laptops/lenovo-e46-notebook/downloads/DS011433). Install the drivers then reboot your system and check whether it appears in Device Manager or not.

Report back in comment section.

Comment: While executing the IN3BTH28WW5.exe i get a message saying -

Comment: "No Bluetooth device was detected. Please make sure that your Bluetooth device is plugged in properly in order to continue installation (cancel installation)"

Comment: @MilindPatwardhan Then I guess It's a hardware problem.

Comment: Thanks, do i need to change any settings in the setup before windows load??, I am able to see the fsquirt.exe in the windows\system32 folder..